# How to create "nested" dropdowns in Excel VBA combo boxes?

Tags: vba, excel

For example,

1. Cash in Bank

   - Account# 1
   - Account# 2
   - Account# 3
2. Payroll Expense

   - Regular
   - Extra
   - Agency

I want to create a combo box that will allow the selection of the main category (e.g. Payroll Expense) while it also allows the selection of the sub categories (e.g. Agency).

Below is an example of these kinds of dropdowns:

[image: Example]

Comment: Use two dropdowns, with the second fed by a choose function which chooses the list to be used in the second drop down...

Comment: @SolarMike my concern is that in accounting, there can be many levels down from the main category. So does that mean I have to "pre-place" the drop downs with many combo box objects? If I look at accounting softwares such as quickbooks, they only have 1 dropdown, but with "nested" dropdowns. Is this not possible in VBA excel userforms?

Comment: The choices are limited by each selection...  select first one and second provides appropriate choices, then select the second and the third provides appropriate choices : sort the logic...

Comment: @MarcSantos well my question would be then, why are you trying to create an interactive drop down menu in Excel? This is not something Excel is equipped to do

Comment: @Rawrplus because it's the only thing I know. Also I am still exploring the limits of VBA

Comment: @MarcSantos I mean that is all fine and dandy. My point here is, it's just something you'll probably bruise your teeth with trying to achieve, when it could be eachieved in matter of minutes with some simple HTML. And I think many here would agree, that HTML is actually much easier to learn than VBA.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks I guess it's pre-placing combo box objects

Comment: @Rawrplus Can you integrate HTML and excel? I have already created a complex program with VBA excel so I was just wondering if there was such a way to do the nested dropdowns in 1 dropdown element. But it appears like there isn't

Comment: @MarcSantos Technically yes, but for compatibility reasons I wouldn't recommend doing so. It's mainly useful for importing / exporting data for web and not much more.  Probably the best question to ask here would be, is there a way to circumvent the multiple dropdown while being able to achieve the same thing?  The pre-placing combo box objects do work, but it is kind of a busy-work, especially when you would have to do it for large sets of drop downs as you described are about to do.

Comment: @Rawrplus perhaps that would be the best question to ask now given nested dropdowns are not possible. I guess I can limit the sub categories to 3 levels to simplify things.

Comment: You could possibly use a TreeView to achieve something similar. Have the dropdown as a Label instead or similar control and then on click show a second userform containing the TreeView

Comment: @Tom thanks i'll look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough example:

Set up two userforms `UserForm1` and `UserForm2`.

`UserForm1` has a label on it.

`UserForm2` has a `TreeView` on it (You'll have to add this to your toolbox -> Right Click on the Tool Box -> `Additional Controls...` -> `Microsoft TreeView Control, version 6.0`)

Then behind `UserForm1` add the following code:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

Behind `UserForm2` add:

```
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "User32" _
    Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
    Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
    Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIndex As Long, _
    ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DrawMenuBar Lib "User32" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" _
    Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

    Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
    Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
    Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIndex As Long, _
    ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function DrawMenuBar Lib "User32" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
#End If

Sub RemoveTitleBar(frm As Object)
    Dim lStyle          As Long
    Dim hMenu           As Long
    Dim mhWndForm       As Long

    If Val(Application.Version) < 9 Then
        mhWndForm = FindWindow("ThunderXFrame", frm.Caption) 'for Office 97 version
    Else
        mhWndForm = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", frm.Caption) 'for office 2000 or above
    End If
    lStyle = GetWindowLong(mhWndForm, -16)
    lStyle = lStyle And Not &HC00000
    SetWindowLong mhWndForm, -16, lStyle
    DrawMenuBar mhWndForm
End Sub

Private Sub TreeView1_Click()
    UserForm1.Label1 = TreeView1.SelectedItem
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Call RemoveTitleBar(Me)

    With Me
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Top = UserForm1.Top + (UserForm1.Height - UserForm1.InsideHeight) + UserForm1.Label1.Height + UserForm1.Label1.Top
        .Left = UserForm1.Left + (UserForm1.Width - UserForm1.InsideWidth) + UserForm1.Label1.Left
    End With

    TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:="Item1", Text:="Parent 1"
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:="Item2", Text:="Parent 2"
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:="Item3", Text:="Parent 3"

    TreeView1.Nodes.Add "Item1", tvwChild, "one", "Item 1, Child node 1"
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add "Item1", tvwChild, "two", "Item 1, Child node 2"

    TreeView1.Nodes.Add "Item2", tvwChild, "three", "Item 2, Child node 1"
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add "Item2", tvwChild, "four", "Item 2, Child node 2"

    TreeView1.Nodes.Add "Item3", tvwChild, "five", "Item 3, Child node 1"
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add "Item3", tvwChild, "six", "Item 3, Child node 2"
End Sub
```

This results in:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

***Click on the grey bar at the bottom of `UserForm2` to dismiss***

You can play around with this a lot more yourself - This is just a quick example of my previous comment. Have a look at adding a `DropDown` picture to the end of the `Label`

Comment: I want to understand a little more about TreeView do you have any good references?

Comment: I don't I'm afraid. Chip Pearson is always a good point of reference though [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/foldertreeview.aspx)

Comment: Btw, this code does not work in 64-bit excel. The parts with `User32`

Comment: @MarcSantos Haven't tested it but have updated it to make it 64bit safe