# How to convert 32-bit excel VBA code to run on 64-bit excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am able to use these codes in my Excel 2007 at the office, but how come I cannot use it in my Excel 2016?

It says that it isn't built on 64-bit, but how do I convert it? The code below is highlighted in red.

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" _
Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long, _
ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function DrawMenuBar Lib "User32" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
```

Error is shown below:
[image: Error]

Comment: https://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp

Comment: More on [PtrSafe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ptrsafe-keyword).

Comment: Private Declare PtrSafe Function as per links suggested

Comment: You have two compiler issues. a) xl2007 uses VB6 and xl2010 (and up) uses VB7. b) You have one system on Win64 and one not. If you are planning to use compiler directives to cover multiple versions and platforms then decide if you are going to cover every possibility or just the ones you need.

Comment: Hi Marc - Have updated my original answer with the answer to this. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964442/how-to-create-nested-dropdowns-in-excel-vba-combo-boxes/50965620?noredirect=1#comment89329852_50965620)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create "nested" dropdowns in Excel VBA combo boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964442/how-to-create-nested-dropdowns-in-excel-vba-combo-boxes)

Comment: @Tom - good find! I think that posts covers basic compatibility.

Comment: @Tom thanks. I asked a new question here because I felt it was a different topic. But feel free to close if ever

Comment: @MarcSantos That's fair - I just voted to close as you asked in two places and had answered it elsewhere

Answer (score 5):

I found this equivalences for x64 systems :

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr


#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" _
    Alias "GetWindowLongPtrA" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
    ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" _
    Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
    ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
#End If

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" _
Alias "SetWindowLongPtrA" ( _
ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
ByVal nIndex As Long, _
ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Public Declare PtrSafe Function DrawMenuBar Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
```

Source : https://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp

I didn't try the functions, I only past this code and it isn't highlighted in red despite of your version in your answer.

Comment: `GetWindowLongA` returns a `Long`. `GetWindowLongPtr` does return a `LongPtr`, and it works for both x86 and x64, so there is no need for a branch to `GetWindowLongA` to begin with, just like you don't have it for `SetWindowLongPtrA`.